# Label every polygon with true/false if it contains point

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, point, point-in-polygon

I have large polygon data set and I want to label every one with *true* if polygon contains point or *false* if it does not. Polygon can contain multiple points, but if just one point fall into polygon it should be true.
With large polygon data set  (about 100 mil polygon and 10 mil points) what is the most efficient time-consuming way to do this using postgis?

This is what I ended up with:

```
select distinct on (poly.id) poly.id, case when st_contains(poly.geom, point.geom) is true then true else false end as contains 
from polygon poly
left join public.poi point
on st_contains(poly.geom, point.geom);
```

Comment: please show us your SQL that you tries so far

Comment: I added a code snipped.

Comment: I'm assuming you have spatial indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get any better than the general query structure, if getting **all** polygons with a `flag` **in a `SELECT`** is your goal.

Nonetheless, some improvements can be applied:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ply.geom)
       COALESCE(ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pt.geom), FALSE) AS flag
FROM   poi AS pt
LEFT JOIN
       polygon AS ply
  ON   ply.geom && pt.geom
;
```

- use `ST_Intersects` for point-in-polygon
- obviously you don't need the `CASE` when `ST_Intersects` returns `BOOL` already
- even if PG *may* be able to cache the spatial relationship function (`ST_Intersects`), there's no need to call it twice; if it doesn't cache, you save 50% of operations with joining on bbox intersection (`&&`)

---

However, if you intend to run an `UDPATE`, better add a `BOOL` column with `DEFAULT FALSE`, or run an `UPDATE` setting the whole table to `FALSE`, then

```
UPDATE polygon AS ply
  SET  flag = TRUE
FROM   poi AS pt
WHERE  ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pt.geom)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer!

Comment: Sometimes ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pt.geom) returns null. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @DrJacoby that's because of the `LEFT JOIN` - whenever a `poi` has no `&&` intersection at all with any of the `polygon`s, `ST_Intersects` is executed with a `NULL` value, and returns it. I added a fallback.